# Excel 2010 - How do I record a macro and play it back for all cells in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to make a macro. I can (barely) figure this out. This macro will perform an operation on a single cell (convert link text into a live link as in [In Excel, I pasted in a bunch of URLs, but they aren't live links -- how do I bulk convert them to live links?](https://superuser.com/questions/301402/in-excel-i-pasted-in-a-bunch-of-urls-but-they-arent-live-links-how-do-i-bul))

**How do I cause this macro to be played against every cell in a column?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to "View" and then click the "Macros" button.
2. This will open a dialog box asking for the name of a new macro. Enter "Test" and click "Create".
3. This will open the VBA editor.  Copy the code from @Lance Roberts in your previous post into this new window.
4. Now go to your spreadsheet and select the range of cells with the hyperlinks you want to fix.
5. Go back to the VBA editor. Press F5. This will execute the code.